# Is there an equilivent to Linq.Expressions.Expression in python?

Tags: python, expression-trees, lambda

I would like to be able to get the expression out of a lambda function much like C# does and parse it into something else?
Example in C#:

```
void Foo<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression
{
// ...
}

Foo<Baz>(someObj => someObj.HasBar);
```

The lambda operator will be traslated to an expression that could be inspected.
What's the equilivent in python?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why would you need this? As much as I love fiddling with compiler-related stuff including ASTs, I wasn't aware that this is useful outside of some extreme metaprogramming.

Comment: @delnan: Because the lambda expression can be translated translated to an SQL statement. I am wondering if the querying API of the django ORM can be improved.

Comment: @delnan: I assume for the same reason there is Expression<> in C#—to translate code to SQL to run it in a database backend. I would be equally interesting to translate to ECMA script to have a web toolkit transparently run things on client-side.

Comment: Ah, so you *are* planning some high octane metaprogramming :)

Comment: @the_drow: Actually now that I wrote the comment about JavaScript, it seems both `compile python to sql` and especially `compile python to javascript` google queries give interesting results.

Comment: @the_drow: Especially you might want to look at what [Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/) does, though that uses the source and calls the compiler rather than starting from compiled code. But than you can also ask the function from which file and line it comes and ask the compiler to re-parse it.

Comment: @JanHudec: I already know it but I have a more severe problem. I'm looking at the python library docs (http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html) and it seems that it might break for any version of python which means that I might need to create a different library for each django supported version.

Answer (score 1):

Python provides full access to the compiled form of code.

```
>>> f = lambda(x): 2*x
>>> f.func_code.co_code
'd\x00\x00|\x00\x00\x14S'
>>>
```

You can, in principle, reverse engineer this to figure out the expression, though it's no mean feat to do so. The dis module might give you a bit of a head-start:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
              7 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.opname[ord(f.func_code.co_code[-2])]
'BINARY_MULTIPLY'
>>> dis.opname[ord(f.func_code.co_code[-1])]
'RETURN_VALUE'
>>>
```

Comment: Is there no better way to do so?

Comment: @delnan: Not quite. The co_code field is the actual bytecode from which you can reconstitute an AST with a relatively simple stack machine. It's fairly arcane stuff, but it shouldn't require more than a few dozen lines of code.

Comment: Is there a library which parses it into something that might be a bit more usable like an object of some sort?